# Why is it difficult to manufacture capacitors in femtoFarad or lower range?

Tags: electrical-engineering

Capacitors available in the market have a lower bound around 1 pF or 0.1 pF. Why is it difficult to manufacture capacitors in femtoFarad or lower range?

Comment: What do you think are the issues? So we don't repeat what you have found already...

Comment: As Niels' answer suggests, the functional value of such a cap would vary by a large percentage depending on how it's installed and what's near it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not that such capacitors are inherently difficult to manufacture. It is that within the bounds of everyday engineering, they have few uses in actual circuits. Note also in this context that you can make an extremely low-valued capacitor simply by bringing one conductor trace on a board close to another.